# Should i extend mysqli class or create my own database conection class?

Tags: php, mysqli

I got the following    class to conect to database and perform queries, i'm new to php so is this the correct way of doing it, or is it wrong to extend mysqli.?

```
 class MyLink extends mysqli
    {

      function getAll(){

       /* Consultas de selección que devuelven un conjunto de resultados */
        $sql = <<<SQL
        SELECT name,lastname
        FROM `user`
        WHERE `deleted` = 0
    SQL;

    if(!$result = $this->query($sql)){
        die('There was an error running the query [' . $this->error . ']');
    }
    return $result;
    }
```

Then i call the class on every page that needs a method in it like this.

```
require_once("../../../../../includes/config.php")
require_once("../../../../../includes/mylink.php")

$db = new MyLink(DB_SERVER, DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD, DB_NAME);
```

Answer (score -1):

Neither, you should use [PDO](http://php.net/PDO) instead; that said, there's nothing wrong in principle with extending mysqli - it's just that PHP itself already contains PDO - a broader, native OOP database class that uses a newer API and is where all the development resources are being dedicated going forward.

Comment: yeah, I hit submit before I really intended to

Comment: It's not true. MySQLi is independent extension and provides few extra features.

Comment: Also, question about "extend or do not extend?". Your answer about "use PDO".

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "independent extension". You're correct that there are some features in mysqli that we have not yet added to PDO, but there are also features that PDO provides which mysqli will not.

Comment: Well, sure - when presented with a false dichotomy, I refused to accept it, and instead pointed out the third option. I'm not aware of any SO rule against that.

Comment: This is comment, but not the answer. OP could use MySQLi or PDO or Whatever -- it does not matter in this context. He wants to know: extends or do not extends. Does your answer provide this information?

Comment: Yes; it additionally provides him with an even better 3rd option.